# Displaying a message based on the value of a field in a PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf

This will likely be painfully obvious but I'm new to JavaScript...

In plain English, I'm trying to achieve this:

- If "Your Score" is equal to or greater than 36 show "Aggressive
  Growth"
- If "Your Score" is equal to or greater than 26 show "Growth"
- If "Your Score" is equal to or greater than 16 show "Balanced"
- If "Your Score" is less than 16 show "Conservative"

What I'm trying to use is this:

```
if (this.getField("Your Score").valueAsString>=36) event.value = "Aggressive Growth";
if (this.getField("Your Score").valueAsString>=26) event.value = "Growth";
if (this.getField("Your Score").valueAsString>=16) event.value = "Balanced";
if (this.getField("Your Score").valueAsString<16) event.value = "Conservative";
else event.value = "";
```

When "Your Score" is less than 16, the form works. If "Your Score" is 16 or greater, it does not work.

Please help!?

Comment: You need to use `else if` for all the ifs after the first one.  If the first one is true, all the others are true as well, except for the `< 16` one.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else  Read up on the basics

Comment: That worked thank you!

Comment: Yep, 16, 26, and 36 should be 1st, 2nd & 3rd for it to work without brackets. And end else is for `NaN`, I guess.

Comment: Can be.  Not "should" be.  Should is an opinion.  Using else if reduces the number of expression evaluations once the first one is true.

Comment: You're twisting my words. I said *"for it to work without brackets"*. And I already agreed it's bad practice. I'm not advocating for it. If we're clinging on words, they definitely do not "need" to use `else if`. Maybe they should.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with brackets or lack of brackets.  The issue is entirely related to `if` statements being independent to each other. @tao

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226066/discussion-between-tao-and-taplar).

Answer (score 0):

The way your code is set up, each `if` is evaluated. So, by sending a score of 170, you have a lot of `if` statements that resolve to `true`:

```
if (score >= 36)
if (score >= 26)
if (score >= 16)
```

But, what you actually want is for the first `if` that meets the criteria to process, otherwise, move to the next one until it resolves `true`. Otherwise, if none are true, do nothing. Doing something simple like adding `else if` will correct this mistake.

```js
const score = 170;

if (score >= 36) console.log("Aggressive Growth");
else if (score >= 26) console.log("Growth");
else if (score >= 16) console.log("Balanced");
else if (score < 16) console.log("Conservative");
else console.log("");
```